# How to analyze words like "Read a book at 9 o'clock tomorrow morning" in DialogFlow correctly?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to find out a way which could parse a sentence in natural English like "Read a book at 2 o'clock tomorrow afternoon" into ["tomorrow", "14:00", "Read a book"] or something like.

I tried some prebuilt agents of DialogFlow, like alarm, reminders, and time, they all fail to parse.

I also tried sentences like "Call mom at 2 this afternoon" or "Call mom at 9", etc, none of them could be extracted correctly.

Is there any problem with my usage, or any alternative API that could match my requirement more precisely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to just parse sentence on create an agent?

Comment: @vitooh, I need to invoke this agent via API in my app.

Comment: OK, but how do you setup the intent?

Comment: @vitooh, so your suggestion is to improve and fill more examples in intents of prebuilt Reminders agent, right?

Comment: You haven't presented what you have done so far so it's hard to say. Theoretically it should work in Dialogflow. Maybe you have to create your custom agent...Anyway I think you should present some try and its result to be able to help in anything.

Comment: Hi @vitooh, got it, I'm now changing my strategy, instead of finding out another API, I'll try to fill more entities to the existing agent of DialogFlow, and make it understand more actions but not only some like "remind" or "alarm". Thanks for your enlightening!